# Changing object/point to custom symbol based on specific name in MapInfo using MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am new to programming and Basic.  I only started trying to use MapBasic and have reviewed a few sites and their reference guide to get an idea of what I can do and would like to do.

For this project I am trying to eliminate a monotonous task that is performed each time a user creates a "custom aerial".  Basically we have a table with a range of 15 to 45 (sometimes more and sometimes less) records that are name specific.  For example, let's say they are Fast Food Users (Taco Bell, McDonald's, KFC) Each time we create an aerial we change each record to their respective custom symbol (which I have created) and it uses up a lot of time.  So what I am trying to figure out is how I can write some code that will automate this task by taking my table "retail.tab" and call on a column ("CustImgName") that contains the custom symbol name (TacoBell.bmp, KFC.bmp, etc) and automatically change it to the custom symbol.

In addition, I would also like to find a way to report back if it matches them all or not so that the user can QC their work before proceeding.

I have tried the Hard Code Thematics tool that is out there, but due to the massive amount of records we use in our database it causes performance issues with MapInfo.

Comment: Can you give us some information about where you are storing your data? Is it stored in a spatial database, like SQL Server 2008/2012, Oracle or PostGIS? Have you tried creating a thematic map based on the TYPE and use this to "change" the display of your points?